# Referencing Multiple Sheets with large sets of Data

Tags: vba, excel

I am fairly new to VBA and having some general obstacles with basic syntax. I am using the below code to trim leading spaces and color code an ActiveSheet I am currently working on.

I have another Worksheet called "Country" that I would like to apply the same logic to the current sheet I am using. I am also having difficulties using the most efficient code to find any cells with values of "AcctTotal" , " CurrTotal" and " BravoTotal" (there are about 14,000 rows of data). I am currently highlighting the whole spreadsheet and utilizing "UsedRange" to find these cells.

To sum it up:
I would like to trim leading spaces and color code any values of "AcctTotal" , " CurrTotal" and " BravoTotal" in two worksheets: "Currency" and "Country"

Sub ColorCodeCurrency()

```
Dim r As Range
For Each r In Selection
    If r.Value = " AcctTotal" Then
        r.Value = LTrim(r.Value)
        Intersect(r.EntireRow, ActiveSheet.UsedRange).Interior.ColorIndex = 15
    End If
Next r

Dim s As Range
For Each s In Selection
    If s.Value = " CurrTotal" Then
        s.Value = LTrim(s.Value)
        Intersect(s.EntireRow, ActiveSheet.UsedRange).Interior.ColorIndex = 40
    End If
Next s

Dim t As Range
For Each t In Selection
    If t.Value = " BravoTotal" Then
        t.Value = LTrim(t.Value)
        Intersect(t.EntireRow, ActiveSheet.UsedRange).Interior.ColorIndex = 35
    End If
Next t
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

Most of the problem is that you're doing the same thing three times.  The 'For Each' statement is going through every cell three times.  If you joined it into

```
    for each r in selection
 if r.value ="AcctTotal" then 
'do something 
elseif r.value = "CurrTotal" then 
'do something else 
elseif r.value = "BravoTotal" then 
'do the third thing 
end if
```

Comment: I agree that is a problem and I will fix that but how do I reference the "Country" worksheet? As of now, it is only applying the code to the active worksheet

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Maudise said, when you refer to your data, you can use syntax like:

```
Sheets("Country").Range("A1:E14000")
```

If it's possible to make changes to your source data, you may find it helpful to format it as a table for easy reference. Use the Name Manager to give the table a useful name. Then, you can say something like:

```
For Each r In Sheets("Country").Range("CountryTable")
```

Comment: I'm not always going to receive 14000 rows, sometimes more. What can I use to best capture all the data?

Comment: As I mentioned, I think using a table is the easiest way to do this. But, if a table is not an option, you could use what IolandaAB suggests to find the last row and the right-most column.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this way:

```
Public Sub ColorCode ()

Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, m As Integer, n As Integer

i = Range("A:A").End(xlDown).Row
j = Cells.End(xlToRight).Column

For m = 1 To i
    For n = 1 To j
        If Cells(m, n).Value < 50 Then
            Cells(m, n).Interior.ColorIndex = 13
        End If
    Next n
Next m
End Sub
```

One solution is to call this code placed in a module into "This workbook" in "Private Sub Workbook_Open()".